# Windows "User Account Control" Prompt Icon Size

Tags: windows, installation, user-account-control

The Windows "User Account Control" dialog displays an icon for the application it is asking about. The icon in the window is 40x40. My executable includes an ICO file with 32x32 and 40x40 icons. Windows uses the 32x32 image and scales it up to 40x40. I am using Inno Setup to create my installer. Is it possible to get Windows to use the 40x40 image instead?

[image: UAC Dialog with Blurry Icon Image]]

The setup icon is defined in the ISS file using

```
SetupIconFile=MyProgSetup.ico
```

(I tried deleting the 32x32 image and leaving just the 40x40 image. Windows uses the 40x40 image but still distorts the image. It looks like it scales it down to 32x32 then back up to 40x40.)

Comment: Could you add details on _how_ you define the icon in your iss file?

Comment: https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=iconssection explains how. I experience the same issue.

Comment: I updated the post to include how I am defining the icon. It is defined using SetupIconFile in the [Setup] section, not the [Icons] section.